# User attempting to sweep answer under rug

Tags: discussion

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165317/dont-affect-positionnig-of-other-elements-on-border-width-changes/38165567) SO question, @Angel Politis offered a totally valid solution. However, he was wrong in saying that the OP's original idea is impossible.

I realize it *is* possible via `box-sizing` and post my own answer.

1h 48m later, Angel [edits his post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38165369/3) in order to mention `box-sizing`. He notes that it is "... not compatible with early versions of Internet Explorer, Safari, Firefox and Opera." This is actually incorrect based on [the link that he himself included in his answer](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing); according to that, it's compatible with everything besides IE 6 & 7.

My answer answers the OP's question more directly instead of offering an alternative like Angel did. Additionally, Angel's answer [is actually compatible with less browser versions than mine](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow). Based off of these two points, my answer is better for the OP.

However, Angel seems to be attempting to sweep my answer under the rug.

SO is about sharing information, not gaining reputation. Angel's actions seem to be born from an inverse moral, so I ask:

Is it okay for Angel to try to keep being the accepted answer like this, especially since the goal of SO is to get the OP the *best* answer (mine)?

Comment: Meh, the question isn't great and the topics have been covered, I'm voting to close it.

Comment: You could post a comment on the answer stating why you believe it is wrong and link to your answer. It's absolutely ok to have answers showing alternative approaches to problems. Let the community decide which one is "best".

Comment: @ModusTollens I left a comment, but that's kinda the point, that Angel is attempting to inhibit the community's ability to choose the best by falsely downplaying mine.

Comment: What, exactly, are you attempting to get out of this question? I don't see "sweeping under the rug". I see a user that edited in more information and a post that has 15 views and hasn't been active for 28 days. What is your end goal with this meta question?

Comment: @Quelklef I don't see it that way. Like you do, Angel attempts to answer the question correctly. Just let it go and let the community decide. Assume good intentions. I see no attempt on downplaying your answer.

Comment: Erm, wait, wouldn't that make [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9675551/17034) the best answer?  Having multiple answers for the same problem with various amounts of lacking detail does not exactly create useful Q+A.  Hopefully Google can sort it out.

Comment: @Quelklef I do understand your frustration, but look also from a different standpoint. What if a user made a certain mistake or omission in his answer, which is otherwise correct, and even accepted? Does he have the right to correct it, even if it was reveal in another answer? I'd probably do, otherwise this answer would stay forever showing incompetence. Lets say, tomorrow his prospective employer would want to look at his skills level on this site. Then what? :)

Comment: @sambul35 This is a very good point. I just thought Angel had noticed his mistake because of my answer and didn't include credit, instead doing the opposite.

Comment: @Quelklef I agree, credit component is important here. I always include credits in my answers, regardless of what weight certain hints or others answers have in it. This is basic fairness to someone else's free contribution. In that regard, the 1st step would be to place a comment in the question reminding about such credit. Often that would be enough, if not, may be this discussion was useful for all parties involved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my answer I wrote ***`"That's not possible, because the elements are relatively positioned and the space each one occupies changes when the border-width changes."`***, because at the time of answering that question that was the only way I knew of that could achieve the optical result the OP requested.

Later on while giving a look at Bootstrap's source code, I saw **`box-sizing: border-box`** and after checking it out at [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) and testing it myself I found that I was in fact wrong when I said ***`It's not possible`***.

So, since my answer is the accepted answer and will always be on top, I thought it would be a good idea to go back to that question and add it as an alternative, so that new users that may stumble upon that question in the future may have a bigger range of solutions to choose from what fits their code best.

---

Stack Overflow is a community built upon selflessness and the willingness of its members to help each other out, so thoughts of the type ***`Angel seems to be attempting to sweep my answer under the rug.`*** don't belong here.

Your claim of my attempting to undermine your answer is completely unfair and has no basis or foundation whatsoever as my answer had been accepted by the OP before yours was even posted.

Moreover, I, myself, was the first to upvote your answer when I saw that there was another answer that proposed this very solution I had just found about, so that the OP can see there was another equally good answer.

[image]

Comment: You're right. I was being selfish, I wanted credit, and I didn't give you a fair chance. I do think I had a legitimate basis and that my question was legitimate (what if I had been right>); however, I posted it, honestly, for very anti-"selflessness and the willingness" reasons. Hopefully I can learn to follow that sentiment better in the future. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome and I hope the misunderstanding is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Votes will hopefully bring the *best* answer to the top, but the one who solves the user's problem is the one that should be accepted. Even if they pick the wrong answer. The user has agency to pick, even if they pick wrong. Don't be discouraged if a user does this. It's 15 rep. You can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink...

Comment: While SE/SO is about answering questions, is it not also about gathering knowledge?

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is just that- the accepted answer. It just means that's the answer the asker believe solved their problem. We shouldn't invalidate that, even if people disagree on the correctness

Comment: @Quelklef Upvotes are more important than the acceptance mark. The answer with the most upvotes is the one the community voted to the top. The acceptance mark just marks the accepted answer (which sometimes isn't the best one).

Comment: @Quelklef if by "gathering knowledge" you mean making other people see your point after they've made it clear that they don't, no. That's a futile enterprise both here and in the real world.

Comment: @Modus Tollens The term "top" is a relative one, as well as upvotes number. It more depends on how hot the topic is at present, rather then on answer quality. I've seen brilliant answers being buried because the topic wasn't hot enough, so no-one cared to read it. It also depends on how simple the topic is. Basic questions and simple answers to these can receive a lot more upvotes than an elaborate answer in an advanced topic, as readers count shrinks.

Comment: @sambul35 I am aware of that, but I don't think there is much we can do about it. Apart from commenting on answers or awarding bounties to good ones, that is. Still, the _acceptance mark_ is not the best indicator of a good answer.

Comment: I agree, such mark also reflects qualifications of the asker. :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 By gathering knowledge I mean creating a website where someone can come for reference, where someone's SO question may also apply to another visitor's issue and so it's important to emphasize the best answer for future visitors. I mean that when I look up a programming question on Google the top result may be an SO link because the answer from 8 years ago is still relevant to me now.

Comment: @Quelklef not always will the best answer have the accept mark. Community voting is a more reliable indicator.

Comment: @Quelklef Strange thing is, I look at applicability of every answer in searched threads, and quite often the best answer is neither highest upvoted, no accepted, because the tasks seldom exactly match, and the ways askers think about approaching the solutions vary. I prefer unique solutions to typical ones, someone may do opposite. In fact, in most cases I use just a small portion of a searched answer, a certain good hint or code tweak from it. :)